# Redirect function not working in Python Flask

Tags: python, forms, flask, redirect, web-applications

I'm sure this has a very simple solution, I have just not managed to find one anywhere on the web (that works in my case). I am trying to build a simple web app and I would like to redirect the user to a predefined @app.route() at the click of a button. I can do it indirectly by displaying a hyperlink, but would obviously much prefer if the redirection was automatic.

This is my 'Home page' >>

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT"])
def f_page():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # print(request.form["action"])
        if request.form["action"] == "Officers":
            # print(request.form["action"])
            return redirect("/in2")
        if request.form["action"] == "Companies":
            return redirect("/in3")
    return '''
        <html>
            <body>
                <p>What do you wish to seed the network with?</p>
                <form method="post" action="/">
                    <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="Officers" /></p>
                    <p><input type="submit" name="action" value="Companies" /></p>
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    '''
```

Note : The commented out 'print(request.form["action"])' was simply included to verify that my code was in fact reaching that point (which it was)

And my '/in2' & '/in3' function is >>

```
@app.route("/in2", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT"])
def in2():
    return("Hello")
@app.route("/in3", methods=["GET", "POST", "PUT"])
def in3():
    return("Hello")
```

After clicking either button I would expect to see a page load with the words 'Hello', but instead  my homepage is loaded and '27.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2021 15:47:33] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 302 -' is displayed in my terminal.

I am aware I can change the page that gets loaded by altering the route in the form action `'<form method="post" action="/">'` but this complicates things further down the line. I was hoping to find  a solution using a similar method to that detailed above.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: My previous comment was off, I removed it. The cause is that your redirect results in an invalid URL. It will be "localhost:5000//in2" (observe the double slash). Remove the leading slashes from the redirect address. Hint: use the  `url_for` function to create your urls.

Comment: @MennoHölscher Thanks!!